# What to have in sources.list on an Ubuntu LTS server (production)?

Tags: ubuntu, update, apt

I have several Ubuntu 10.04 LTS servers in production and I'm using apticron to check that my software is up to date, **security-wise**. However, by default, Ubuntu has the `lucid-updates` repository enabled. This means lots of low-priority updates ([such as this](http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg2331650.html)) that I don't need and thus, extra work for me.

Is it okay to just remove the lucid-updates line(s) in sources.list? I still get security updates via `lucid-security`, right? So, this is what my sources.list would look like.

```
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
```

**Update**: will it cause problems to remove the `lucid-updates` line, if I have already updated some packages from there? (I'm thinking of what will happen if there are both low-priority and security updates for a package.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is okay to do this.

Comment out the top two lines, leave the bottom two lines as they are.

Alternatively check out the help page on [automatic security updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates)

The only caveat I would add is that if you want to dist upgrade later, you will have to update all the packages anyway. 
Depending on how you prefer to manage your updates it may be simpler to simply update all packages as you go along to save a huge update when you want to dist-upgrade.